# DCT filter image in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, dct

I used the below function to filter an image. Basically it sets coefficients of DCT to 0 except for top-left 8x8 elements, which means it filter out all high frequency part and only left the low frequency part.

```
function I_out = em_DCT_filter(I_in,N)

I_trim = double(I_in)-128;

MYDCT=dctmtx(N);
dct = @(block_struct)MYDCT*block_struct.data*MYDCT';
B=blockproc(I_trim,[N,N],dct);

mask = zeros(N,N);
mask(1:N/4,1:N/4)= 1;

AnselmMask = @(block_struct)block_struct.data.*mask;
BMask=blockproc(B,[N N],AnselmMask);

InverseDct = @(block_struct)MYDCT'*block_struct.data*MYDCT;
BReversedl = blockproc(BMask,[N N],InverseDct);

I_out= uint8(BReversedl+128);
```

After processing, an image looks like this:
[image: before filter] [image: after filter]
I need the function removes the details in the image (e.g. patterns on the sweater, shadow on the pants), which it seems working fine. However, the function also makes the image very fuzzy. How can I remove the details, as well as keeping the region structure clear? For example, the sweater/pants region will be more uniform coloured region than before.

Comment: Do you have to use the DCT?  Why can't you just blur the image with spatial filtering?

Answer (score 1):

You basically applied "Local Low Pass Filter".
No wonder "Fuzzy" look is the result, you removed data in the High Frequency we usually interpret as details and "Sharpness".

What you really should do is remove High Frequency details yet keep large edges in tact.
A good way to do is use something like Anisotropic Diffusion.
By using the optimized parameters you'll be able to achieve the look you're after.
In general those methods are called image abstractions.

Here's a great Open Source code for advanced Anisotropic Diffusion:

https://github.com/RoyiAvital/Fast-Anisotropic-Curvature-Preserving-Smoothing

Work with, if you can contribute, it would be amazing.